# Set alarm for several days

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm working on alarm clock app. I've faced with one problem. I do not know how to set alarm for several days. I've already tried the code that is below but in log I saw this `Wed Apr 06`(didn't change any date so it **should** be nearest tuesday and friday). What do I do wrong? May be I should set alarm separately for every other day?

This is my code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY);
                //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
                Log.e("Point_1","Calendar " + calendar.getTime());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService_alarm.this,MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this,intent.getIntExtra("Size", 1),intent1,0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are logging the time before setting the hour and minutes from the time picker,

your code si working fine but to display the time that was set to the Alarm in your log you have to move the `Log.e` to after you set the Calendar to the hour and minute from your picker so your code should look like this :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY);
            //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Log.e("Point_1","Calendar " + calendar.getTime());
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService_alarm.this,MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this,intent.getIntExtra("Size", 1),intent1,0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Also since you are making an Alarm for several days it would be wise to save all the set alarms and to add a receiver to detect when the device has been booted since your alarms are cancelled on reboot and will need to be added again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the issue is that I can not set my alarm for several days at once.

Comment: what do you mean an alarm for several days ? I dont seem to understand what you are trying to achieve, do you want an alarm set for multiple days ? if so yes you need to set an alarm for each day separately

Comment: So, I can not just add Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY) and Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY) to set alarms for these days?

Comment: Please note that Calendar.add((int field,int amount) does not add a date to the Calendar, but adds the specified amount to the existing date, the Calendar instance only holds one date at a time but what you could do is set the calendar to date1 using `calendar.set()` then add the alarm with that date then use `calendar.set()` to set it to date2 again then add the alarm again. Check this explanation for better understanding https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_add.htm

Comment: @Steve also you are using AlarmManager.setRepeating() which will set the alarm to a specified time then repeat itself based on the specified interval which you indicated to be "7*24*3600*1000" i am not sure if this is what you want but to set a one time alarm use `.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent);`

Comment: Well, I wanted my alarm, for example for monday, be repeated every new monday

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY);
```

is not correct. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) you will see that there is no such method.

By writing `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` you are telling system that you are entering some value as day of the week. But instead of one specific day you are entering two. `Calendar` object is used to store **one** specific date.

Therefore, in order to get set alarms for several days, you need to set each of the alarms separately. For this reason you may create separate `Calendar` objects or reuse one by changing the time. However, you have same receiver class for both alarms. Therefore, you need to create different pending intents to make alarm manager differentiate them. For this reason I have shown you the example with different `request_code`.

```
calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);

calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService_alarm.this, MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this, 1, intent1, 0);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this, 2, intent1, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, pendingIntent1);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, pendingIntent2);
```